# Rest API combining two lists

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, lookup-column, sharepoint-rest-api

I have two lists with look-up columns, Address and Employee. GetID (Address) looks up list Employee. Below is the rest query. But its throwing error (404 Bad req).
Can anyone give some insight into why this is getting a 404?

`_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Address')/items$Select=Address_Line1,Address_Line2,Street_No,State,Pin_Code,GetID/Emp_Fname,GetID/Emp_Lname,GetID/Emp_Mname,GetID/Phone_No,GetID/Designation&$expand=GetID`

Comment: What version of SharePoint? Have you successfully used REST calls on this environment before?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `?` before `$Select`. Refer below URL. It should work. Try it and check ....

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Address')/items?$Select=Address_Line1,Address_Line2,Street_No,State,Pin_Code,GetID/Emp_Fname,GetID/Emp_Lname,GetID/Emp_Mname,GetID/Phone_No,GetID/Designation&$expand=GetID
```